# Why is this SQL INSERT INTO statement throwing an error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, psycopg2

So my code looks like:

```
sqlpoptable = "INSERT INTO datas(createdon) VALUES (%s);"
data = ('a')
cursor.execute(sqlpoptable, data)
postgresConnection.commit()
```

Which works fine. However if I try to add any length to the variable such as:

```
sqlpoptable = "INSERT INTO datas(createdon) VALUES (%s);"
data = ('aa')
cursor.execute(sqlpoptable, data)
postgresConnection.commit()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is going on that is making using any more than one character throw an error? Ultimately what I am trying to do is timestamp on entry for this column.
data type is character varying 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `cursor.execute()` must be a *sequence*, such as a list or a tuple.

It looks like you tried to make a tuple here:

```
data = ('aa')
```

However, that is not a tuple; it is just a plain string.  The syntax for one-element tuples is a bit funny:

```
data = ('aa',)
```

Your first example worked because strings are *also* considered to be sequences (of individual characters), and you used a one-character string, which matches the number of `%s` tokens in the sql statement.

Your second example did not work because you used a two-character string, so each character was interpreted as its own separate item, which was too many values for the single `%s` token.

Answer (score 0):

Your First Statement Is Executed Because Your Are Putting correct character that is 'a' but in second case you are not putting correct character that is 'aa' thats why you got error.

character hold only length of one not more than one.